# URLSession.DataTaskPublisher doesn't publish values when throws an error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I'm new to the Combine Framework and SwiftUI in general, I'm stuck trying to handle errors from a `dataTaskPublisher`.
The API I'm working with is returning a JSON file containing the data of the user and a 204 status response code if the user doesn't exist.

I created a simple struct to manage the User data and his state after the request is done:

```
struct User: Decodable{
    enum UserState {
        case unknown, Valid, errorDecoding, errorNetwork, noUser
    }
    
    // Attributes of the decodable struct
    // ...
    //
    
    var status: UserState = .unknown
}
```

In the `ViewModel` I created an instance of `User` and a function that gets the data from the API. I just want to assign the data to the User instance and set the status of the user accordingly to the status of the API request.

This works fine when the API return some valid result and the publisher finishes assigning the data in the `receiveValue`.

The issues starts when the `tryMap` throws some errors: the errors are correctly handled by `mapError` and then the `receiveCompletion` is executed, however when it finishes the status of the user is still set to .unknown as if the user instance was never edited.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user = User()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func getuser() {
        enum UserError: Error {
            case unknown, noUser, network, badURL, decoding
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/JSON")!
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { (data, response) in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw UserError.badURL }
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 204 {
                    throw UserError.noUser
                } else if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    throw UserError.network
                }
                return data
            }
            .decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .mapError({ error -> UserError in
                switch error {
                case is Swift.DecodingError:
                    return .decoding
                case is UserError:
                    return error as! UserError
                default:
                    return .unknown
                }
            })
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(.decoding):
                    print("Error decoding")
                    self.user.status = .errorDecoding
                case .failure(.network):
                    print("Error network")
                    self.user.status = .errorNetwork
                case .failure(.noUser):
                    print("Error no User")
                    self.user.status = .noUser
                case .failure(.badURL):
                    print("Error bad URL")
                    self.user.status = .errorNetwork
                case .failure(.unknown):
                    print("Error unknown")
                    self.user.status = .unknown
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            }, receiveValue: { user in
                self.user = user
                self.user.status = .Valid
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Any ideas about what i did wrong here?
Is there maybe a better way to accomplish what i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Btw, `User` doesn't conform to `Decodable`.

Comment: Why do you think (or how do you know) that it's `.unknown`? Also, unrelated, but convention is to use lowercase for enum cases, so change to `.valid`

Comment: FWIW, I wrote a page that returned 204, and this successfully set status to `.noUser` case without problem. I'd add breakpoint inside `sink` completion handler and step through and see if the problem that `user` is not getting set, or whether there is some other problem whereby the updated status is not getting reflected in your UI.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the test you did @Rob, i just figured out that I did a stupid error in the actual code (quite embarrassing...), in the declaration of `User` I used a `Class` instead of a `Struct`. Changing that made the code work again. I also used `CodingKeys` to make the `User` conform to `Decodable`, i didn't want to make the code too long to read here.

Comment: Hopefully you've solved your problem now. By the way, you asked whether there was a “better way to accomplish what i need”. It feels a bit duplicative to have `status` effectively mirror nearly all of the `UserError` values. I'd just capture the error as a separate property and remove the status from the `User`. That simplifies the code a bit.

Comment: The logic should also be pushed into the UserError enum.  For example you should be able to init it with a. raw value of the response code.  Also it should be CustomDebugConvertible or CustomStringConvertible so you can just print it out without the switch.